# Variable with interval check jQuery

Tags: jquery, intervals

I assigned my variable for the viewport width and heigt like this

```
var width1= window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth ||  document.body.clientWidth;
var height1 = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight ||  document.body.clientHeight;
```

But i want to have it checked regularly for any window changes. So my "full size" div can change size with the screen.

I tried this :

```
var width1= setInterval(function() {window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth ||  document.body.clientWidth},1000);
var height1 = setInterval(function() {window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight ||  document.body.clientHeight},1000);
```

But it doesnt work for some reason.

Can someone suggest what I need to do?

Comment: It exists the event listener 'window.onrezise'. I don't know which version of jquery do you use, so you have either to use the method '.bind() or '.on()'

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an event listener for the window resize event:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).on('resize', function(event) {
        var width = $(this).width();
        var height = $(this).height();
    });
});
```

In javascript you will usually use this event-based model to handle interactions, instead of having to poll for changes.

http://api.jquery.com/resize/

http://api.jquery.com/on/